# while running huggingface gpt2-xl model embedding index getting out of range

Tags: python-3.x, language-model, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to run [hugginface](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/gpt2.html#tfgpt2lmheadmodel) gpt2-xl model. I ran code from the [quickstart](https://huggingface.co/transformers/quickstart.html) page that load the small gpt2 model and generate text by the following code:

```
from transformers import GPT2LMHeadModel, GPT2Tokenizer
import torch

tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained("gpt2")
model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained('gpt2')

generated = tokenizer.encode("The Manhattan bridge")
context = torch.tensor([generated])
past = None

for i in range(100):
    print(i)
    output, past = model(context, past=past)
    token = torch.argmax(output[0, :])

    generated += [token.tolist()]
    context = token.unsqueeze(0)

sequence = tokenizer.decode(generated)

print(sequence)
```

This is running perfectly. Then I try to run `gpt2-xl` model. 
I changed `tokenizer` and `model` loading code like following:
  tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained("gpt2-xl")
  model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained('gpt2-xl')

The `tokenizer` and `model` loaded perfectly. But I a getting error on the following line:

```
output, past = model(context, past=past)
```

The error is:

```
RuntimeError: index out of range: Tried to access index 204483 out of table with 50256 rows. at /pytorch/aten/src/TH/generic/THTensorEvenMoreMath.cpp:418
```

Looking at error it seems that the embedding size is not correct. So I write the following line to specifically fetch the config file of `gpt2-xl`:

```
config = GPT2Config.from_pretrained("gpt2-xl")
```

But, here `vocab_size:50257`
So I changed explicitly the value by:

```
config.vocab_size=204483
```

Then after printing the `config`, I can see that the previous line took effect in the configuration. But still, I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was actually an issue I reported and they fixed it.
 https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/2774